# Which is better - subqueries only or joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have two tables in SQL Server 2008 -

```
Sales.SalesOrderHeader --> CustomerID(FK, int, not null), OrderDate
(datetime, not null), etc...
Sales.Individual --> CustomerID(PK, FK, int, not null), ContactID
(FK, int, not null), etc...
```

I have to find the the customers (ie CustomerID and the Corresponding ContactID) that ordered something on the last day orders were placed.

This query is used to find the last OrderDate

```
   select MAX(Soh.OrderDate) 
   from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Soh
```

Now, the next thing to do is get the CustomerID and Contact ID. I thought of
two ways - Using only sub queries and where clauses OR Join and one sub query.
The two approaches are shown below:

--Style1: Using only subquery

```
select Si.CustomerID, Si.ContactID
from Sales.Individual as Si
where Si.CustomerID in
( 
  select Soh.CustomerID
  from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Soh
  where Soh.OrderDate = 
  (
    select MAX(Soh.OrderDate) 
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Soh
  )
) 
order by Si.CustomerID, Si.ContactID
```

--Style 2: Using inner join

```
select CustOnLastDay.CustomerID, Si.ContactID
from
(
  select Soh.CustomerID, Soh.ContactID
  from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Soh
  where Soh.OrderDate = 
  (
    select MAX(Soh.OrderDate) 
    from Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Soh
  )
) as CustOnLastDay
inner join Sales.Individual as Si
on CustOnLastDay.ContactID = Si.ContactID
order by Si.CustomerID, Si.ContactID
```

**Question -** Which is better, sub queries only or joins (In general and this case) ?
Btw, most of my tables don't have more than 14-15k rows.

Thanks.

Comment: Why I need the ContactID also ? I have to look it up in another table to get the name of the customer (ID) as well. But, I did not include that part because it would make the question too long, perhaps without adding any value to it. If you want my final query, I can put that too.

Comment: Generally, you want to avoid nested subqueries for the sake of clarity and readability.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Yes, that makes sense. But is there an impact on speed of execution of query or anything else ?

Comment: Using a JOIN does not necessarily return the same result as using a sub-query. But if they *are* equivalent, SQL Server will notice that and both versions will most probably use the same execution plan.

Comment: As noted in my comment to one of the answers (and as @a_horse_with_no_name also says), if they are functionally equivalent, then *generally* they will perform the same. This is because most modern professional optimizers such as SQL Server's (or Oracle's or DB2's) are *very* good and figure this out. Many older versions (10+ years) and many current non-professional DBMS's (such as MySQL) do still demonstrate this problem of subqueries being significantly slower than JOINs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JOINs RDBMS can create an execution plan which makes it faster as compared to sub query. In many cases you will find that JOINS are comparatively faster than subquery. However when  they are functionaly equivalent, they will perform the same. Subquery loads all the data for processing

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) says:-

> Many Transact-SQL statements that include subqueries can be
>   alternatively formulated as joins. Other questions can be posed only
>   with subqueries. In Transact-SQL, there is usually no performance
>   difference between a statement that includes a subquery and a
>   semantically equivalent version that does not. However, in some cases
>   where existence must be checked, a join yields better performance.
>   Otherwise, the nested query must be processed for each result of the
>   outer query to ensure elimination of duplicates. In such cases, a join
>   approach would yield better results.

For example:-

If you are doing something like this:-

```
select * from table1 where exists select * from table2 where table2.parent=table1.id
```

then it is better to use **JOIN**

Check this [Example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/06/06/sql-server-subquery-or-join-various-options-sql-server-engine-knows-the-best/) which explains the difference between SUBQUERY and JOIN performance:-

```
USE AdventureWorks
GO
-- use of =
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Employee E
WHERE E.EmployeeID = ( SELECT EA.EmployeeID
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeAddress EA
WHERE EA.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID)
GO
-- use of in
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Employee E
WHERE E.EmployeeID IN ( SELECT EA.EmployeeID
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeAddress EA
WHERE EA.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID)
GO
-- use of exists
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Employee E
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT EA.EmployeeID
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeAddress EA
WHERE EA.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID)
GO
-- Use of Join
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.Employee E
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeAddress EA ON E.EmployeeID = EA.EmployeeID
GO
```

Now compare the execution plan:-

[image]

Comment: I am "new" to sql so I cannot understand what you said. Can you give me some proof for this ?

Comment: Thanks. What are the reasons for this ? -->  In Transact-SQL, there is usually no performance difference between a statement that includes a subquery and a semantically equivalent version that does not. However, in some cases where existence must be checked, a join yields better performance.

Comment: @blasto:- I would recommend you to go through the link which I have shared you will surely get something fruitfull :)

Comment: I saw the link. It only mentions some points. It does not give the reasons or logic behind those points.

Comment: @blasto:- Updated the answer with another example. Hope that helps!! :)

Comment: You say "*In most cases you will find that JOINS are comparatively faster than subquery.*", this is not true.  In most cases where they are functionaly equivalent, they will perform *the same*.  This is evidenced by your own quotation from MSDN: "*In Transact-SQL, there is usually no performance difference between a statement that includes a subquery and a semantically equivalent version that does not.*"  The same is generally true for all modern production SQL DBMS's (such as Oracle and DB2) because they have excellent SQL Optimizers.

Comment: @RBarryYoung:- Sir please dont get it wrong. I know what you are saying and I know that MSDN says that. I just wanted to convery that in most cases it is compartively(may be negligible) faster than queries and I have verified this result on my own. I am again saying that I am not denying your statement!! :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung:- The query which I took in my example took nearly 3 sec when I executed it with subqueries on my database with very huge data in tables. But when I executed it with joins it took ~1.4 sec :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung:- Updated my answer to avoid any misleading concept. Hope that is fine now!!!???

Comment: @RahulTripathi  I could give counter-examples all day long.  Neither addresses the point of what happens in *most cases* though.  In *most cases* they are the same, and your own quote proves it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung:- I agree Sir. And I have updated my answer as well neither I am denying to it!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Join is generally preferred to the multi-level nesting with subqueries. In general joins are faster as SQL server Engine can better optimize this type of query.

Answer (score 0):

Inner joins are typically faster than subqueries as the subqueries are typically executed each time for whatever the current record is in the first part of the from clause...

Also, you could do better by having the MAX() order date as it's own query so it's not done on every record and join down stream.  Ensure you have index on your order header table.  I would have it based on (orderdate,customerid) so it's a covering index and doesn't need to go back to the raw data pages for other criteria as the order date and customer ID are in the index that it can utilize.

I would revise the query as...

```
select
      soh2.CustomerID,
      si.ContactID
   from
      ( select max( soh.orderdate ) MaxDate
           from sales.salesorderheader soh ) as JustDate
         join sales.salesorderheader soh2
            on JustDate.MaxDate = soh2.OrderDate
            join Sales.Individual SI
               on soh2.CustomerID = SI.CustomerID
   order by
      soh2.CustomerID, 
      si.ContactID
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither! Look into the [ranking functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for some inspiration. ANSI SQL calls these *window functions*. You may find DENSE_RANK() is exactly what you need to grab the latest date in an elegant way:

```
select *
from (
    select Si.CustomerID, Si.ContactID,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY soh.OrderDate DESC) as DenseRank 
    from Sales.Individual Si
    inner join SalesOrderHeader soh on soh.CustomerId = Si.CustomerId
) subquery
where subquery.DenseRank = 1
```